# can't find NDK camera and media native API symbols when linking libavdevice.a to libffmpeg.so

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ndk

I'm using NDK tools to build ffmpeg shared lib which will be used in my
   android rtsp project.All needed components are compiled/linked as seperate
   static libs, and at last these libs will be linked as a single shared lib.
   Everything goes well except the last step. error happens when linking
   libavdevice, all symbols in NDK camera and media can not be found, error
   log:

```
libavdevice/android_camera.c:702: error: undefined reference    
to 'ACameraCaptureSession_stopRepeating'
libavdevice/android_camera.c:706: error: undefined reference 
to 'ACameraCaptureSession_close'
libavdevice/android_camera.c:711: error: undefined reference 
to 'ACaptureRequest_removeTarget'
libavdevice/android_camera.c:712: error: undefined reference
to 'ACaptureRequest_free'
libavdevice/android_camera.c:717: error: undefined reference 
to 'ACameraOutputTarget_free'
libavdevice/android_camera.c:722: error: undefined reference 
to 'ACaptureSessionOutputContainer_remove'
libavdevice/android_camera.c:724: error: undefined reference 
to 'ACaptureSessionOutput_free'
libavdevice/android_camera.c:729: error: undefined reference 
to 'ANativeWindow_release'
libavdevice/android_camera.c:734: error: undefined reference 
to 'ACaptureSessionOutputContainer_free'
libavdevice/android_camera.c:739: error: undefined reference 
to 'ACameraDevice_close'
libavdevice/android_camera.c:744: error: undefined reference 
to 'AImageReader_delete'
libavdevice/android_camera.c:749: error: undefined reference 
to 'ACameraMetadata_free'
libavdevice/android_camera.c:756: error: undefined reference
to 'ACameraManager_delete'
libavdevice/android_camera.c:172: error: undefined reference
to 'ACameraDevice_getId'
libavdevice/android_camera.c:163: error: undefined reference
to 'ACameraDevice_getId'
libavdevice/android_camera.c:392: error: undefined reference
to 'AImageReader_acquireLatestImage'
libavdevice/android_camera.c:483: error: undefined reference  
to 'AImage_delete'
libavdevice/android_camera.c:345: error: undefined reference
to 'AImage_getPlanePixelStride'
libavdevice/android_camera.c:346: error: undefined reference
to 'AImage_getPlaneData'
...
```

Here is my build script which is ran on my Windows 7 x86_64 PC.

```
#!/bin/bash
export TMPDIR=D:/other/AndroidDevelopment/ffmpeg-4.0.2/ffmpegtemp 
NDK=D:/software/app/android_sdk/ndk-bundle
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-28/arch-x86_64/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64
CPU=x86_64
PREFIX=./android/$CPU

function build_one
{
    ./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-static \
    --enable-jni \
    --enable-pthreads \
    --enable-mediacodec \
    --disable-asm \
    --disable-shared \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-symver \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/x86_64-linux-android- \
    --target-os=android \
    --arch=x86_64 \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags=" -isysroot $NDK/sysroot  -I$NDK/sysroot/usr/include/x86_64-linux-android" \
    --extra-ldflags=-pie 
make clean
make -j4
make install

$TOOLCHAIN/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ld \
-rpath-link=$SYSROOT/usr/lib64 \
-L$SYSROOT/usr/lib64 \
-L$PREFIX/lib \
-soname libffmpeg.so -shared -nostdlib -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no- undefined -o \
$PREFIX/libffmpeg.so \
libavcodec/libavcodec.a \
libavfilter/libavfilter.a \
libswresample/libswresample.a \
libavformat/libavformat.a \
libavutil/libavutil.a \
libswscale/libswscale.a \
libavdevice/libavdevice.a \
-lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker \
$TOOLCHAIN/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/libgcc.a \
}
build_one
```

Comment: If you want to build your `libffmpeg.so` for 64-bit emulator (as suggested by `$CPU`), note that native NDK camera will only work for *emulated* camera on for API=27 or 28, see https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/issues/509

Comment: Save yourself some trouble and use a [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain).

Comment: @DanAlbert, I don't think in this case there will be a noticeable benefit with standalone toolchain.

Comment: @AlexCohn: would be able to delete some pieces of that script and it would be more portable across NDK versions

Comment: @DanAlbert true. But if you want to have different variants, e.g. all four currently supported ABIs, and probably different platform levels, and keep this across the dev. team, standalone toolchains add more hassle than they resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Your `…-ld` command needs explicit references to the Android native libraries:

```
-lcamera2ndk -lmediandk -lnativewindow
```

---

Actually, I don't understand this obsession with the `build_one` shell function. Here is the minimal script that works for me, with NDK r18b2 and ffmpeg 4.0.2:

```
export NDK=whatever
export CPU=x86_64
export CROSS=$NDK/toolchains/$CPU-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/$CPU-linux-android-
mkdir android_$CPU
cd android_$CPU
../configure --enable-static --enable-jni --enable-pthreads --enable-mediacodec \
  --disable-asm --disable-shared --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay \
  --disable-ffprobe --disable-doc --disable-symver \
  --cross-prefix=$CROSS --target-os=android --arch=$CPU --enable-cross-compile \
  --sysroot=$NDK/platforms/android-28/arch-$CPU \
  --extra-cflags="-isysroot $NDK/sysroot -I $NDK/sysroot/usr/include -I $NDK/sysroot/usr/include/$CPU-linux-android" \
  --extra-ldflags="-pie -L$NDK/platforms/android-28/arch-$CPU/usr/lib64 -lc -lm" \
  --ld=$CROSS-ld
make CONFIG_V4L2_OUTDEV=no
$CROSS-ld -soname libffmpeg.so -shared -nostdlib -Bsymbolic \
  --whole-archive --no-undefined -o libffmpeg.so \
  libavcodec/libavcodec.a libavfilter/libavfilter.a \
  libswresample/libswresample.a libavformat/libavformat.a \
  libavutil/libavutil.a libswscale/libswscale.a  libavdevice/libavdevice.a \
  -L$NDK/platforms/android-28/arch-$CPU/usr/lib64 \
  -lc -lm -lz -lcamera2ndk -lmediandk -lnativewindow
```

Note that I disabled **v4l2 output**. My compilation failed for **libavdevice/v4l2.c**, because the NDK definition of **ioctl()** was not compatible with **ffmpeg**.